# How to redirect stderr to a remote shell?

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

There are two ways to realize my idea as following,

```
(innobackupex --stream=tar ./ | ssh root@192.168.0.105 "cat - > backup.tar") 2> backup.log
innobackupex --stream=tar ./ 2> backup.log | ssh root@192.168.0.105 "cat - > backup.tar"
```

But both of them can't redirect stderr to a remote file.Is there any way to work arround this problem?

Comment: (innobackupex --stream=tar ./ | ssh root@192.168.0.105 "cat - > backup.tar") 2>&1 |  ssh root@192.168.0.105 "cat - > backup.log"

Comment: A more simple approach `(innobackupex --stream=tar ./ | ssh root@192.168.0.105 "cat - > backup.tar") 2>backup.log && scp backup.log root@192.168.0.105:~`